# Trouble styling polymer element

Tags: html, css, polymer, web-component

I'm having trouble styling a polymer paper button element. In the following example, I'm not sure why my styles for `#rate` are not being applied to the paper button.

```html
<script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/platform.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-button/paper-button.html" rel="import">

<polymer-element name="my-element" noscript>
  <template>
    <style>
           :host #rate {
             background: yellow;
             color: green;
             height: 25px;
             line-height: 8px;
             margin: 0;
             text-transform: none;
      }
    </style>
    <paper-button id="rate">rate/reply</paper-button>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
<my-element></my-element>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I copy your code the style section will not apply, but if I manually retype :host #rate{..} with all the same info it works fine. Maybe a hidden character that is causing a parsing issue.

Well that was a fun one to trouble shoot, just confirmed in notepad++ your indention is with tabs, looks like a bug in polymer's parser. If you just delete the tabs from each line it works fine

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Changed `:host #rate` to `#rate`

```html
<script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/platform.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-button/paper-button.html" rel="import">

<polymer-element name="my-element" noscript>
  <template>
    <style>
#rate{
background:red;;
color: yellow;
height: 40px;
width:100px;
margin: 0;
text-transform: none;
}

    </style>
    <paper-button id="rate">rate/reply</paper-button>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
<my-element></my-element>
```